# Rows of coins in libgdx?

Tags: 2d, libgdx, scrolling

I have my coin image in the assetLoader class, then I import it into gameWorld.

**My question is, how can I draw() rows of coins without having to write out 15 different coins?**

i.e., coin1, coin2, coinRect1, coinRect2, coinX1, coinX2, etc.
Wouldn't it be more efficient/easier on memory&performance to create a 'coin' class and use a loop somehow?

It's a vertical scroller so the coins should be lined up vertically and disappear individually as the playerRect intersects the coinRect.
[image: illustration of the game]

The coins should not intersect the obstacles and the randomly generated number of coins in any row (e.g. a row of 6 coins all lined up) should be between 1 and 10.
If I used a loop (somehow...) the integer i would be the randomly generated number of coins in any row, so that 1<=i<=10, and if coin.position intersected obstacleRect then it i would become i-1 so that the coins stopped right before the obstacle.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with libgdx, but in general:

Yes, you should definitely create a coin class. If all coins use the exact same sprite, you can make the sprite variable `static`, so that it's only created once and shared by all instances of coin. Alternatively, if there is some variance between coins (for example, some coins are red and some coins are blue), you could implement the flyweight design pattern for similar efficiency.

As for creating the coins, you can have the class `Coin` take x and y positions as constructor arguments. Then you can create as many as you like, wherever you like, and store them in some sort of data structure (for example, an ArrayList). To make them generate in a line, offset their y positions by a fixed value multplied by the iteration of the loop they're being created in. Sample code to do this (won't compile, see code comments for details):

```
// Data structure for holding coins
ArrayList<Coin> coins = new ArrayList<Coin>();

// Generate a random number between one and ten (inclusive). You'll
// need to define rand.
int max;
int min;
int randomNumber = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

// Create that number of coins in a line
for (int i = 0; i < randomNumber; i++)
{
    // Position the coin will be created at. You'll need to
    // define distanceBetweenCoins.
    position = Vector2(positionX, 
                       positionY + (distanceBetweenCoins * i));

    // Only create a coin here if the position is not inside the
    // obstacle rectangle. You'll need to look up the libgdx method
    // to do this. This looks to be the way to go:
    // https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Intersector.html
    if (!position.Intersects(obstacleRect))
    {
        coins.add(new Coin(position));
    }
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is a great opportunity for you to learn how to use Stage2D for your game.  It already handles the rendering of tons of objects for you, including culling of actors.  Actors are capable of having location, rotation, scaling, input, and actions all associated with them and it's all managed for you.  Handling collision with them isn't all too difficult either, but does typically require another step.

An example of how you could use a Stage for collision, rendering, and input to do what you're looking for.

```
int score;

Stage stage;    
Texture coinTexture;
Texture obstacleTexture;
Group coinLayer;
Group obstacleLayer;
Actor player;

public void create() {
    stage = new Stage();

    coinTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/coin.png"));
    obstacleTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/coin.png"));
    coinLayer = new Group();
    obstacleLayer = new Group();
    player = new Image(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/player.png"));
    stage.addActor(coinLayer);
    stage.addActor(obstacleLayer);
    stage.addActor(player);

    stage.addListener(new InputListener(){
        //input code goes in here
    });

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
}

/**
 * We use this method to add coins, which may be added to our level
 */
private Image createCoin(float x, float y) {
    Image coin = new Image(coinTexture);
    coin.setPosition(x, y);
    return coin;
}

/**
 * We use this method to add obstacles to our level
 */
private Image createObstacle(float x, float y) {
    Image obstacle = new Image(obstacleTexture);
    obstacle.setPosition(x, y);
    obstacleLayer.addActor(obstacle);
    return obstacle;
}

/**
 * Because the layers that we are placing actors into may have unequal
 * local coordinate systems, we need to map their values to where they
 * are in the stage to calculate absolute collision.
 */
private boolean collides(Actor a, Actor b) {
    Vector2 a_coord = a.localToStageCoordinates(new Vector2(0, 0));
    Vector2 b_coord = b.localToStageCoordinates(new Vector2(0, 0));
    Rectangle a_rect = new Rectangle();
    Rectangle b_rect = new Rectangle();

    a_rect.setPosition(a_coord);
    a_rect.setSize(a.getWidth(), a.getHeight());

    b_rect.setPosition(b_coord);
    b_rect.setSize(b.getWidth(), b.getHeight());

    return a_rect.overlaps(b_rect);
}

/**
 * Here we create a line of coins until it overlaps with
 * one of our obstacles.  We generate anywhere between 1 and 10 coins
 */ 
private void createCoinLine(float x, float y) {
    int amount = MathUtils.random(1, 10);
    boolean done = false;
    for (int i = 0, cy = y; i < amount && !done; i++, cy += coinTexture.getHeight()) {
        Image coin = createCoin(x, cy);
        //check for coin overlapping any obstacles
        SnapshotArray<Actor> obstaclesSnapshot = obstacleLayer.getChildren();
        Actor[] obstacles = obstaclesShapshot.begin();
        for (int n = 0; n < obstacles.length && !done; n++) { 
            Actor obstacle = obstacles[n];
            done = collides(coin, obstacle);
        }
        obstaclesSnapshot.end();
        //add the coin to the coin group if we did not overlap any obstacles
        if (!done) {
            coinLayer.addActor(coin);
        }
    }
}

public void render() {
    float delta = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    stage.act(delta);

    //game movement and collision logic goes here

    //check for coin collision with player for points
    SnapshotArray<Actor> coinsSnapshot = coinLayer.getChildren();
    Actor[] coins = coinsShapshot.begin();
    for (int i = 0; i < coins.length; i++) { 
         Actor coin = coins[i];
         if (collides(coin, player)){
             coin.remove();
             score++;
         }
    }
    coinsSnapshot.end();

    stage.draw();
}
```